# Mysql query group by per hour return zero if no data found for an hour

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a three mysql database table which contains the call record of the customer company. I want to fetch the data from the database for a company group by per hour. If there is no data for an hour, it should return Zero.

I am executing this query, but am getting the result for that hour only for which there is a data in the database.

This is my query.

```
select ph_Plans.Comp_ID, Plan_Type, ph_Companies.CompanyName,
    (sum(call_length_billable)*100)/(Plan_Limit*60) as total,
    hour(calldate)
from ph_Plans
join ph_Companies
    on ph_Companies.Comp_ID = ph_Plans.Comp_ID
join cdr
    on cdr.CompanyName = ph_Companies.CompanyName
where Plan_Type='Per_Min'
    and date(calldate)='2012-10-01'
    and ph_Companies.CompanyName='"ReadySpace-EN"'
group by hour(calldate);
```

This is the result that am getting.

```
+---------+-----------+-----------------+--------+----------------+
| Comp_ID | Plan_Type | CompanyName     | total  | hour(calldate) |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+--------+----------------+
|      44 | Per_Min   | "ReadySpace-EN" | 3.7467 |              1 |
|      44 | Per_Min   | "ReadySpace-EN" | 9.4933 |             18 |
|      44 | Per_Min   | "ReadySpace-EN" | 1.6600 |             20 |
|      44 | Per_Min   | "ReadySpace-EN" | 3.7333 |             21 |
|      44 | Per_Min   | "ReadySpace-EN" | 4.6067 |              2 |
|      44 | Per_Min   | "ReadySpace-EN" | 7.6533 |             23 |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+--------+----------------+
```

But I want the result from zeroth hour to 23 hour. If no data then it should return zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a `JOIN`, you only `JOIN` on tables that both have data that corresponds to the Columns being JOINed. What you want to do is a `LEFT JOIN` when you still want results where there is no corresponding data in the other table.

Something like this:

```
select ph_Plans.Comp_ID, Plan_Type, ph_Companies.CompanyName,
    if(call_length_billable IS NULL, 0, (sum(call_length_billable)*100)/(Plan_Limit*60)) as total,
    ifnull(hour(calldate), 0) hour
from ph_Plans
left join ph_Companies
    on ph_Companies.Comp_ID = ph_Plans.Comp_ID
left join cdr
    on cdr.CompanyName = ph_Companies.CompanyName
where Plan_Type='Per_Min'
    and (date(calldate)='2012-10-01' OR calldate IS NULL)
    and (ph_Companies.CompanyName='"ReadySpace-EN"' OR ph_Companies.CompanyName IS NULL)
group by hour(calldate);
```

Comment: I have executed this query but still, it's returning the same result as earlier. Please help me.

Comment: You have where conditions that seem to require the data in the other tables. I have put in checks for if they are null, just test to see if that's closer to the result you want.

Comment: Sorry, but still am stuck at the same point and getting the same result as earlier. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Which table has the missing "data"? ph_Plans, ph_Companies or cdr?

Comment: Table cdr is having missing data. This table is having a column call_length_billable which stores the call record. What I want is, suppose for a particular hour there is no call record in the database, it should return zero value.

Comment: Ok i modified the query again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can generate 0 to 23 hours. You may find both in this demo.

1. using temp table
2. using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY`

   - ### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89ff2/1)

If we use the most typical method, that is using a temp table left joining with your tables.
Please connect this to your main query given the below assumptions.

Sample Query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(P.ID,0),
COALESCE(P.CALLDATE,0),
COALESCE(HOUR(P.CALLDATE),0) 
FROM NUMBERS A
LEFT JOIN
PLAN P
ON A.N = HOUR(P.CALLDATE)
GROUP BY A.N
;
```

Results:

```
| COALESCE(P.ID,0) | COALESCE(P.CALLDATE,0) | COALESCE(HOUR(P.CALLDATE),0) |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                1 |    2013-01-03 01:11:14 |                            1 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                4 |    2013-01-03 09:51:02 |                            9 |
|                3 |    2013-01-03 10:50:20 |                           10 |
|                2 |    2013-01-03 11:31:24 |                           11 |
|                5 |    2013-01-03 12:30:00 |                           12 |
|                6 |    2013-01-03 13:41:01 |                           13 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                7 |    2013-01-03 16:19:08 |                           16 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|                8 |    2013-01-03 20:18:30 |                           20 |
|                0 |                      0 |                            0 |
|               10 |    2013-01-04 22:21:50 |                           22 |
|                9 |    2013-01-03 23:01:44 |                           23 |
```

- **Assumptions**:

Since you have showed the results generated from your tables, I have used the same query to join with 0-23 hour data table. Plus there doesn't seem to be the full table schema to create them in the above demo. Further it's not mentioned which table has the column `calldate`, so I assumed it's in **`Plan_Type`** table.

- PS: removed earlier code as it takes more space in this answer.

Comment: @saurabh please take a look at the logic used here. I assumed your joins were correct. Please comment.

Comment: That's why I said it untested. ;-)

Comment: @Saurabh I just updated the answer. If you can provide us with table schema (ph_companies, ph_plan, cdr) and some sample data, I would be able to connect these and provide you one final query as well. But I hope you will get the idea looking at the above. BTW what's `cdr` table?